# APFS disks may not be used as bootable install media

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning

I accidentally installed macOS Ventura Beta and it doesn't support Xcode 13.

I wanted to install macOS Monterey on a separate volume. So I can use the good old Xcode 13 there instead of Xcode 14 Beta.

I downloaded the Install macOS Monterey.app.

Using Disk Utility, I created a volume called "MacOS2022".

Then in Terminal, I tried to create a bootable installer like this:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MacOS2022
```

But it gives an error saying: "**APFS disks may not be used as bootable install media**."

```
Ready to start.
To continue we need to erase the volume at /Volumes/MacOS2022.
If you wish to continue type (Y) then press return: Y
APFS disks may not be used as bootable install media.
An error occurred erasing the disk.
```

This is output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS2022               688.1 KB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 3.6 GB     disk1s3
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s4
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s5
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     806.2 GB   disk1s6
   6:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            12.4 GB    disk1s7
   7:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 12.4 GB    disk1s7s1

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +13.1 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Shared Support          12.8 GB    disk2s2
```

This is output of `mount`:

```
/dev/disk1s7s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s3 on /System/Volumes/Preboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s5 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s8 on /System/Volumes/Update (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s6 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s7 on /System/Volumes/Update/mnt1 (apfs, sealed, local, journaled, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/MacOS2022 (apfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/Shared Support (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, nobrowse)
```

Using Disk Utilities, I also don't see any option to create a "Mac OS Extended" volume. I can only create APFS volumes. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Using Disk Utility, I created a volume"* I think that was the issue. You didn't create a new partition, you just created a new volume within the existing APFS Container.

You really need to be doing this on a removable, disposable drve, SD or USB stick, 16GB or more.  In Disk Utility, press Cmd/2 so you can see Devices rather than just Volumes, then 'Erase'. GUID/HFS+ should then be amongst the options.

It *is* possible to force this onto your existing drive, but I wouldn't - there is the danger of 'sawing at the branch you're sitting' on if anything goes wrong.

Comment: I am a bit confused on the concept of external USB bootable installation: So I will get an USB drive, erase it to GUID/HFS+, run the createinstallmedia to kind of make the external USB a bootable Monterey installation, then when installing, I install Monterey into the USB drive?

Comment: You can't install to the same drive, no [there's not enough room, it will need at least 30GB if not more, plus it will be slow as all hell, unusably so.] Once booted to the installer, you can then create a new Partition [not volume] on your internal & install to that.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed second OS successfully!

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it! :)